# Function lipsitz.test {generalhoslem} is not working for object clm{ordinal}

Tags: r, goodness-of-fit

I am now tring to test the goodness of fit of an ordianl model using `lipsitz.test` {generalhoslem}. According to the [document](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/generalhoslem/generalhoslem.pdf), the function can deal with both polr and clm. However, when I try to use `clm` in the `lipsitz.test`function, an error occurs. Here is an example

```
library("ordinal")
library(generalhoslem)
data("wine")
fm1 <- clm(rating ~ temp * contact, data = wine)
lipsitz.test(fm1)

Error in names(LRstat) <- "LR statistic" : 
'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
In addition: Warning message:
In lipsitz.test(fm1) :
n/5c < 6. Running this test when n/5c < 6 is not recommended.
```

Is there any solution to fix this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is off-topic and should be on CrossValidated. It's partly a problem with the coding of the test and partly about the statistics of the test itself.

There are two problems. I've just spotted a bug in the code when using `clm` and will push a fix to CRAN (corrected code below).

There does however appear to be a more fundamental problem with the example data. Basically, the Lipsitz test requires fitting a new model with dummy variables of the groupings. When fitting the new model with this example, the model fails and so some of the coefficients are not calculated. If using `polr`, the new model gets the warning that it is rank-deficient; if using `clm`, the new model gets a message that two coefficients are not fitted due to singularities. I think this example data set is just unsuitable for this kind of analysis.

The corrected code is below and I have used a larger example dataset on which the test runs.

```
lipsitz.test <- function (model, g = NULL)  {
  oldmodel <- model
  if (class(oldmodel) == "polr") {
    yhat <- as.data.frame(fitted(oldmodel))
  } else if (class(oldmodel) == "clm") {
    predprob <- oldmodel$model[, 2:ncol(oldmodel$model)]
    yhat <- predict(oldmodel, newdata = predprob, type = "prob")$fit
  } else warning("Model is not of class polr or clm. Test may fail.")
  formula <- formula(oldmodel$terms)
  DNAME <- paste("formula: ", deparse(formula))
  METHOD <- "Lipsitz goodness of fit test for ordinal response models"
  obs <- oldmodel$model[1]
  if (is.null(g)) {
    g <- round(nrow(obs)/(5 * ncol(yhat)))
    if (g < 6) 
      warning("n/5c < 6. Running this test when n/5c < 6 is not recommended.")
  }
  qq <- unique(quantile(1 - yhat[, 1], probs = seq(0, 1, 1/g)))
  cutyhats <- cut(1 - yhat[, 1], breaks = qq, include.lowest = TRUE)
  dfobs <- data.frame(obs, cutyhats)
  dfobsmelt <- melt(dfobs, id.vars = 2)
  observed <- cast(dfobsmelt, cutyhats ~ value, length)
  if (g != nrow(observed)) {
    warning(paste("Not possible to compute", g, "rows. There might be too few observations."))
  }
  oldmodel$model <- cbind(oldmodel$model, cutyhats = dfobs$cutyhats)
  oldmodel$model$grp <- as.factor(vapply(oldmodel$model$cutyhats, 
                                         function(x) which(observed[, 1] == x), 1))
  newmodel <- update(oldmodel, . ~ . + grp, data = oldmodel$model)
  if (class(oldmodel) == "polr") {
    LRstat <- oldmodel$deviance - newmodel$deviance
  } else if (class(oldmodel) == "clm") {
    LRstat <- abs(-2 * (newmodel$logLik - oldmodel$logLik))
  }
  PARAMETER <- g - 1
  PVAL <- 1 - pchisq(LRstat, PARAMETER)
  names(LRstat) <- "LR statistic"
  names(PARAMETER) <- "df"
  structure(list(statistic = LRstat, parameter = PARAMETER, 
                 p.value = PVAL, method = METHOD, data.name = DNAME, newmoddata = oldmodel$model, 
                 predictedprobs = yhat), class = "htest")
}

library(foreign)
dt <- read.dta("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsbdemo.dta")
fm3 <- clm(ses ~ female + read + write, data = dt)
lipsitz.test(fm3)
fm4 <- polr(ses ~ female + read + write, data = dt)
lipsitz.test(fm4)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, WIth the corrected code, the `lipsitz.test` function is now woking well with my `clm` model. However, `pulkrob.chisq` and `pulkrob.deviance` functions are not working for my `clm` model. I have more than one categorical independent variable and the error is `Error in 1:nrow(yhat) : argument of length 0
In addition: Warning message:
In yhat$score <- apply(sapply(1:ncol(yhat), function(i) { :
  Coercing LHS to a list`. Thank you for your help..

Comment: It's doing something to the matrix of predicted probabilities that I thought I'd fixed testing. Thanks for pointing it out. Will upload a fix to CRAN with this.